# Dynamically changing Linked Services/Datasets in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

We require the ability the to perform a lookup into a config table that will let us know the Server and Database and allow us to change it for subsequent lookups.   I can set it up so it up dynamically where it prompts me for the Server and Database – but that process wouldn’t work for us as this process will be running unattended.

For the purposes of this discussion, assume we have a table, Config, which looks like:

ID  Server  Database
1   A       POC1
2   B       POC2
3   V       POC3

And I use a Lookup function in ADF which contains the query:
select Server, Database from Config where id = 1

I then will get the results from this query to set the Server and Database in the Linked Service and Data Set so that I can issue another lookup such as

Select bank_name, bank_etl, bank_rules from bank_table (in the server/database I just looked up in the Config Table) - and continue along with the rest of the ADF process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Switch activity.According to the Server Database in the Lookup activity's output,execute different activity.

Below is my test pipeline.

[image]

Setting of Switch:

[image]

You need to create source dataset before so that the second Lookup activity can use it as source.

Comment: Hi - I did do that and can get the process to work - but each time it prompts me to enter parameters - at which point I do nothing but hit Go - and the process works fine.  Just trying to figure out how to prevent parameters prompt from coming up so that I can automate without human intervention.  Note: Same thing occurs in both Deg and Trigger.

Comment: parameters prompt appears because you create some parameters  in your pipeline.How about changing parameters to variables?

Comment: @RobertM Do you have any other doubt？If no, can you mark this as answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: All of the examples used parameters - I will give variables a try.  Do you have any examples or docs that you could point me to that will show best practices in terms of using variables?

Comment: you can use variables in expression,like @variables('your variable name') to get it's value.you can also use append or set activity to change the value.You can refer to [set variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) and [append variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-append-variable-activity).